# Extract Information From Logs

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Unable to grep third field "Email From":
While I'm using this command to `grep` first two fields:

```
echo "TimeStamp  Email To:  Email From:" && awk '{print $1,$6}' logs
```

Logs:

```
2016-05-23 11:01:40 [1005583] 1b4ivg-004DZf-GX ** mustafa@hotmail.com F=<abbas@DomainName> P=<abbas@DomainName> R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp H=mx2.hotmail.com [65.54.188.72]:25 I=[IP Address]:56910 X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/CN=*.hotmail.com": SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<abbas@DomainName> SIZE=275286: 550 SC-001 (BAY004-MC1F14) Unfortunately, messages from IP Address weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.
2016-05-23 11:12:53 [1015989] 1b4j6h-004GIq-Ob ** tariq@hotmail.com F=<corporate-kbl@DomainName> P=<corporate-kbl@DomainName> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp H=mx3.hotmail.com [65.55.37.120]:25 I=[IP Address]:51605 X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/CN=*.hotmail.com": SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<corporate-kbl@DomainName> SIZE=17484: 550 SC-001 (COL004-MC4F44) Unfortunately, messages from IP Address weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.
```

Want to get:

```
 Timestamp:        Email To:               Email From:
 2016-05-23        mustafa@hotmail.com     abbas@DomainName
 2016-05-23        tariq@hotmail.com       corporate-kbl@DomainName
```

I have to grep third field email address within "F=<>" not "$7", If we grep field "$7" in below mentioned logs it gives me recipient address.

```
 2016-05-23 10:19:03 [954152] 1b4iGS-004027-BM ** icljapan@hotmail.com (mail@icljapan.com) <mail@icljapan.com> F=<mavis@eonboom.cn> P=<mavis@eonboom.cn> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp H=mx2.hotmail.com [65.55.37.120]:25 I=[136.243.219.141]:35485 X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/CN=*.hotmail.com": SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<mavis@eonboom.cn> SIZE=375119: 550 SC-001 (COL004-MC4F12) Unfortunately, messages from 136.243.219.141 weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about

```
  awk '{ printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$6,substr($7,4,length($7)-4) ;} ' logs
```

or with headers

```
  awk 'BEGIN {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n","Timestamp","email to","email from" }
             { printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$6,substr($7,4,length($7)-4) ;} ' logs
```

update for new precision

```
awk 'NF>6 { d=6 ; while ( ! ($d ~ /^F=/ ) ) d++ ; printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",$1,$6,substr($d,4,length($d)-4) ;} ' logs
```

where

- `NF > 6` ensure at least 6 field
- `d=6 ; while ( ! ($d ~ /^F=/ ) ) d++` scan for field like `F=` beware if no such field, inifite loop will occur.
- `substr($d,4,length($d)-4)` same as before, extraction on found field.

this give

```
2016-05-23      mustafa@hotmail.com     abbas@DomainName
2016-05-23      tariq@hotmail.com       corporate-kbl@DomainName
2016-05-23      icljapan@hotmail.com    mavis@eonboom.cn
```

Comment: Please check my comment in second answer, i was unable to write here due to limited characters.

Comment: Dear i have deleted the post as per your direction, now i have edited in original post, please check it.